# Map and Pair - std::get<0>(map.find(val)) error C++

Tags: c++

This code at the indicated lines are both producing the

error: Get is not a member of 'std'

Additionally the code also does not accept .first and .second notation and throws the error that they aren't declared in this scope.

```
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <iterator>
   #include <map>
   #include <utility>
   #include <vector>
   #include <queue>
   using namespace std;
   ...
   std::pair <int,int> pairs;
   queue <int> quads;
   map<int,std::pair<int,int> > pairSets;
   ...
   int parseValue(int searchVal)
   {
    int tempVal;
     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
         for(int j = 1; j < count; j++)
           {
         tempVal = data[i]+data[j];
         if(pairSets.find(searchVal-tempVal) != pairSets.end())
           {
             quads.push(data[i]);
             quads.push(data[j]);
             quads.push(std::get<0>(pairSets.find(searchVal-tempVal))); //These lines are producing errors
             quads.push(std::get<1>(pairSets.find(searchVal-tempVal)));
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Unfortunately i am not as familiar with c++ programming than i am a with C#, i am struggling to find the reason for this error through the C++ source code, i believe i am using maps and pairs incorrectly but i can't find any resources to indicate in what way i am misusing them.

I would appreciate any help or advice anyone has to offer, thank you.

Comment: Find returns an iterator rather than key value directly

Comment: `find()` returns an iterator, which is a pointer. You need to `->second` rather than `.second`

Comment: @Kai oh i had to do -> second.first and ->second.second to get the value inside the map inside the pair, thank you both so much for the help!